# How to rollback Windows Phone 8.1 update?

Tags: 8.0, 8.1, update

Is there any way to rollback windows phone 8.1 to 8 ?

Comment: I'm just curious, why do you want to rollback the updated system?

Comment: Apparently there is a way to roll back from WP8.1 - > WP8.0 by installing Nokia Software recovery tool. You can find detailed [instructions here](http://nokiaviews.com/downgrade-from-wp8-1-to-windows-phone-8-0.html).

Answer (score 21):

There's no universal way to roll any Windows Phone device back to 8.0 that's guaranteed to work 100% of the time.

From the [Windows Phone Preview for Developers page](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop/devpreview):

> **You cannot revert or return to a prior operating system release version after** you have updated your phone to a preview update. We will move you forward to a "released state," but we cannot take you back to a prior "released state."

For most people on the Developer Preview programme, the best advice is to simply wait until the official 8.1 update becomes available from their phone manufacturer and/or carrier (e.g. in Nokia's case the Lumia Cyan update).

---

That said, it might be possible to flash your phone with the 8.0 firmware, thus rolling back the OS version. For instance, Nokia Lumia phones can be flashed using the [Nokia Software Recovery Tool](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987). However, success will depend on the availability of a ROM with the desired OS and firmware versions. For instance, when I tried to flash my Lumia 920, the only available firmware was the one containing Lumia Cyan, and I suspect this will be the case for more and more Lumia models as the Cyan rollout continues. That said, if 8.0 is still available for your phone, or if you're also fine with the Cyan firmware version, then this Nokia tool can help you downgrade (or sidegrade, as the case may be) your phone's firmware.

For other phone makers, similar tools may be available, though I'm not aware of any.

Comment: how about Settings --> About --> Reset your phone?

Comment: @RayCheng Reset your phone only wipes your phone back to the current operating system as if it were brand new and never been used before.

Comment: @caschw, so won't that help OP to rollback to whatever it was before?

Comment: @RayCheng As far as I know, reset just deletes your settings, apps and personal files and restores factory settings. It doesn't actually restore a previous version of the operating system.

Comment: @RayCheng Correct, it was warned in the Preview for Developers app, that "Once you've taken an early update, you cannot revert to a prior state."

Comment: Actually, Flash your phone using Nokia Care Suite and you should be fine (:

Comment: You're assuming the OP has a Nokia phone, which is not a given (although a fair guess, given Nokia's market share).

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can for Nokia phones, it's very simple and easy.
Nokia has released a tool for recovery you can download [here](http://download.fds-ncom.nokia.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/NokiaSoftwareRecoveryToolInstaller.exe)
After downloading the file:

1. Install the program.
2. Run the program.
3. Plug in your phone.
4. Let the PC and program recognize your phone.
5. The last official update for your phone should be available, which is WP8.
6. Recover the system to the version shown by the tool.

Notes:

1. Some phones may not have a recovery version I don't know the reason for that, maybe carrier restrictions of some sort.
2. This tool only works for Nokia devices.

Comment: And that works with any Windows Phone device regardless of brand?

Comment: I only tried it on my lumia1520, I'm not sure about the rest. But you can try plugging the phone to your computer and running the tool, if it recognizes your phone the answer is yes. If not then no.

Comment: Can you summarize the guide in the link to make your answer more useful?

Comment: Sure thing, I'm new here and still learning how to do stuff. But I'll do it in a couple hours.

Answer (score 1):

https://youtu.be/2u_oTLHWQaY

here is my video to downgrade from latest version of 8.1 to 8.0

Comment: can you outline the steps in your answer just in case the link to the video goes dead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes for Nokia phones. You can push the current offical ROM for your phone with [Nokia Software Updater For Retail](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Unbrick-Your-Phone-with-Nokia-Software-Updater-for-Retail-390799.shtml).

This is generally a great tool to have anyway and can also fix issue of indefinite spinning cogs.