# Will I "possibly" get stuck in Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview?

Tags: 8.1

According to this article there's a possibility to get stuck in Windows Phone 8.1 Dev Preview:

http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/two-simple-steps-get-cortana-working-windows-phone-8-1-outside-us-1444771

> It is also possible that Microsoft may discontinue updating its
>   software with this app, meaning you could forever be stuck on Windows
>   Phone 8.1.

Although I highly doubt it, is this true? That I will not be able to update to newer versions than 8.1 and/or the official version of 8.1?

Comment: Of course that's not true, but even it is, I still rather be on 8.1 than <= 8.0. The improvements are just too much to miss.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That article is rife with factual inaccuracies.

The Windows Phone 8.1 Preview for Developers is, for all intents and purposes, the final version of Windows Phone 8.1. It is **not** a beta version, and although bugs can (and do) exist, calling it "likely to be buggy" is misleading. The only substantial difference between the dev preview and what will be released later this year is the carrier- and manufacturer-added firmware updates. And the delays associated with those firmware updates is precisely why Microsoft launched the dev preview programme - so interested consumers can get their hands on the latest and greatest as soon as possible. (Well, that, and developers being able to start testing their apps with 8.1.)

Yes, it's true that if you upgrade to the dev preview, there's no way (or at least [no easy way](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3606/1401)) to go back to a previous version. It will *not*, however, affect your ability to receive future updates, including those from your carrier or manufacturer. Should Microsoft ever "discontinue updating its software with this app", that would just mean the end of the Preview for Developers programme, and it certainly doesn't mean anyone who installed the preview would be stuck with it.

For more information, see [All you need to know about the Windows Phone 8.1 'Preview for Developers'](http://www.wpcentral.com/how-sign-windows-phone-81-preview-developers) at [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com).

Comment: "And the delays associated with those firmware updates is precisely why Microsoft launched the dev preview programme - so interested consumers can get their hands on the latest and greatest as soon as possible." No, Microsoft releases the dev preview so that *developers* can optimize their apps before it becomes generally available. Enthusiasts getting early access is just a welcome side effect IMO.

Comment: @akid Ostensibly, yes, this is for developers, but if you consider that a) this is basically the final version, and b) it's freely available to everyone, I don't think there can be any doubt that the primary goal of this programme is so that WP users don't have to wait after manufacturers and carriers to get OS updates. Nevertheless, I've updated my post to reflect that the preview is also aimed at developers.

Comment: @akid It *IS* called the developer preview, but that is partly to scare off people who may not know better. Before Windows Phone 8 came out, Microsoft promised enthusiasts that there would be a mechanism to get updates sooner. The fact that you don't have to be a registered developer confirms this.

Answer (score -2):

It could be, It couldn't also, it depends on the Microsoft, we can't do anything to force the Microsoft to give the latest updates to us anytime also. In this article, it means that you can't get the newer version after the Official update of the Windows Phone 8.1. By the way, it was just the rumor from the ibtimes, it was not absolutely the correct info also, so we do have some patience to wait for the next update from the Microsoft. :)