# What is sacrificed by installing the Windows Phone 8.1 preview?

Tags: lumia, 8.1, update

What will be sacrificed by installing the Windows Phone 8.1 preview? I just purchased a Lumia 925 and switched carriers. So far I like it, but my original intent was to install the preview. Now, before I start, it would be nice to know what will be sacrificed and not able to work once it is done (like the Nokia camera apps, or functionality like BT, GPS, etc.)

Links to explanations would be great! Tips from personal experience awesome. Links for forums welcome.

Comment: Guarranty may be invalid.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **Nothing**.

---

Long answer: I think this question may have been prompted by the words "developer" and "preview", so let's put those concerns to rest - the Windows Phone 8.1 Preview for Developers is basically the final version of Windows Phone 8.1, just without the manufacturer and carrier firmware updates. As explained [in this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3694), the 8.1 preview is not a half-baked beta version, and installing it won't prevent you from getting the upcoming Lumia Cyan firmware update (ditto for other manufacturers).

That said, certain things are different from 8.0. These are mostly minor things, but a few (such as the new Xbox Games and Xbox Video apps, or the un-integration of social networks from the People and Photos hubs) have received some criticism, so in a way you can consider yourself to be sacrificing their more functional 8.0 equivalents. However, you most definitely will not be sacrificing anything significant, definitely not important functionality like Bluetooth or GPS.

Additionally, depending on your manufacturer and carrier, you *might* be sacrificing your [warranty](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/develop/devpreview).

Overall, though, Windows Phone 8.1 is a big improvement over 8.0, and installing the preview is strongly recommended.

Comment: Thanks... I would not want to miss out on some of the Nokia Camera apps.  However, I do like the features of the social connector in outlook...  and I was looking forward to seeing what it could do in the phone.  Perhaps If I switch before I get that far... I won't miss it.   Thank you for taking the time to post an answer.

Comment: No problem. I'm running the 8.1 preview myself on a Lumia 920 and haven't noticed any problems so far. All the camera apps work normally. If this answer helped you, consider upvoting and/or accepting it. See http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for more.

Answer (score 3):

Sacrificed!? Nah, I don't think so, but you're surely gonna miss the following features

- Music... Now Xbox Music
- Me integration
- Facebook integration
- Photo Hub integration

They are actually just a few, but I personally liked it (and used it quite often!) when I had Windows Phone 8.0 OS

Comment: Hi,  THanks for taking the time to answer.  If there are any others that you can think of... or send me a link to a list... this is what I am looking for.  This way I can at least try some of them... to see if it is an improvement.  I get the feeling Facebook will be integrated in one way or another.  So far, it can get darn confusing when you can integrate FB, twitter, linkedin, and others through outlook.com, outlook 2013, your phone (android/windows) and your windows phone.  Surely they have some kind of integration now?  My bucket list to understand.

Comment: They still have Fb integration but for that you will have to download Fb App on your phone in Windows Phone 8.1. This change was done because of some lack of functionalities in earlier versions, for instance in windows phone 8.0 you cannot "like" photos or posts.

Comment: Do you have any references  that suggest this is permanent, or is this solely based on using the developer preview version (which might still change prior to general release)

Comment: http://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/24jtcy/hi_im_joe_belfiore_from_the_windows_phone_team_ama/ch7vrir

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded my Samsung Ativ S Neo from 8.0 to 8.1PfD and lost nothing but the Sprint Zone in the app store. Not a loss, if you ask me. The process took two updates to 8.0 and the final upgrade to 8.1 and it took almost an hour. If there is anything missing, I'm not noticing it. I personally like the new music app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running 8.1 on a Lumia 1520, and while some of the hub integrations have been removed (photos, me, etc already mentioned), I haven't missed any of them.  I run the Facebook Beta, which was just updated to increase integration with WP8.1.  There is no issue with any of the sensors or radios (gps, bt, nfc, etc).  In fact, most work better than ever, and finally AT&T users get Data Sense app as well as the new Storage Check and WiFi Sense.

The new features far outweigh the loss of some small degree of social integration.  The Action Center is great and Cortana works great.  I like being able to tell her "Tell my wife I'm on my way home" as I'm walking out the door at work, and she'll text her for me.  In Cortana's Notebook, you define your inner circle, which allows you to assign aliases to contacts, so I don't have a contact called wife, it's aliased for Cortana.

I also like the lock screen themeing options, as well as the start page background.  More and more apps have a transparent tile option, and there are apps now that let you override some apps that don't.  The new Podcast app is great, too.

There are many more new features - I whole heartedly recommend installing this update as soon as possible.  I upgraded both my Daughter and Granddaughters' Lumia 920s.  Granddaughters went fine, but daughters phone required a hard reset, and she lost some pictures since she didn't have syncing to OneDrive (skydrive) turned on.  Make sure you have all of the backup options enabled before you apply the update.