# Chat option in lumia 520 Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: 8.1, facebook, chat

I just updated my Nokia Lumia 520 to the 8.1 dev preview and I have noticed that I can no longer get Facebook messages through text messages, as well as not being able to switch to Facebook as an option when replying, or sending a message to a contact. After the install of 8.1 it seems that I need an facebook app to do this.

Does anybody know if there is a setting that I may have missed, or if this is intended, or just not available in the current build? It would be a real shame to lose such a feature, I have come to rely on it very often and found that it makes keeping in touch with my friends and family quite easy.

Comment: Facebook integration with Messaging is removed in 8.1

Comment: ...at the moment (it's still a developer preview)

Comment: they must inlude in upcoming update ..,
we just need it

Answer (score 3):

The facebook chat option was removed. You can use the Facebook app to chat with your Facebook friends.

EDIT: The chat option has been removed from the Facebook app. You need to install the [Facebook Messenger](http://www.windowsphone.com/s/?appid=3219d30d-4a23-4f58-a91c-c44b04e6a0c7) app.

Answer (score 2):

Facebook integration was removed in Windows Phone 8.1. One of the things that 8.1 users miss. To see what other things we miss then [follow this thread](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3808/5091)