# How do I update to Windows Phone 8.1 Update to enable Cortana in Australia?

Tags: 8.1, cortana, 8.1-update-1

How do I update my phone to Windows Phone 8.1 Update (version 8.10.14214.329 or higher) in order to enable Cortana in Australia?

I'm currently running version 8.10.12397.895.

Answer (score 2):

**If you have a Microsoft/Nokia Lumia phone**:

According to Microsoft's official [Lumia Update Availability in Asia Pacific](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/wp8-availability-in-asia-pacific) page, the only Lumia model that has received Windows Phone 8.1 Update (8.10.14147.180) is the Lumia 930. If that's the phone you have, you should be able to go to Settings → Phone update, and download and install the latest version from there.

For all other Lumia devices, you'll need to install the [Preview for Developers](http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96) app and opt in to the preview programme. This should enable your phone to receive OS updates through the same Settings → Phone update process. Note that this will only give you the OS update and won't include the manufacturer- and carrier-specific updates that you get with the Lumia firmware releases (e.g. Cyan and Denim). For more information, see the following questions and their answers:

- [Will I “possibly” get stuck in Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3692/1401)
- [What is sacrificed by installing the Windows Phone 8.1 preview?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3803/1401)

**If you have a non-Lumia phone:**

Check your manufacturer's and/or carrier's website for information about whether Windows Phone 8.1 Update should be available for your device. If it isn't, you'll have to use the Preview for Developers app, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Currently using Lumia 730. I was not able to get Cortana to work with the default English(Indian) Speech installed. I installed UK English & it works fine now.