# Preview for Developer on BLU Win HD

Tags: 8.1, developer-preview

The latest Preview for Developer version is 8.10.14214.329 (I believe).

Has anyone ever installed it on BLU Win HD? After the installation are there any known issues or something is broken?

If I install the preview version now, once Microsoft + manufacturer release the formal update, do I have uninstall preview version first?

Comment: The first part of your question seems pretty open-ended. Questions should ideally be based on actual problems you face, not hypothetical "what if?" scenarios. As for your second question, see [Will I “possibly” get stuck in Windows Phone 8.1 Developer Preview?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3692/1401) and [WP 8.1 rollout - Can I uninstall Developer Preview now?](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5354/1401)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Developer Preview, which is an OS update not firmware update, for Windows Phone is the same for all devices - HTC, Lumia, Samsung, etc.

As the Developer Preview is primarily for **developers**, there can be small issues but generally the releases have been very stable so far.

Typically, when you have a newer build of the OS installed, via the Developer Preview programme, you won't get the *official release* as you'll always be ahead of it. The firmware updates are different, and are released by the manufacturer.

If for some reason you want to back to the *official release*, you'll have to re-flash your device back to factory restore version. That would require a restore tools such as the [Lumia Software Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987), which is for Lumia devices only.

Comment: The Preview for Developers programme is for enthusiasts as well as developers. Also, getting an official firmware release on top of the dev preview version doesn't require flashing the device.

Comment: Thanks, the information is helpful. The reason I am asking is because Cortana currently does not support Canada yet, but the Preview for Developers does. I don't want to switch country to US in order to use Cortana. So I am thinking to give Preview for Developers a try.

Comment: I'd give it a try, I have it running on several phones with no issues on the current build.