# Windows phone upgrade to 10 stopped in middle, now the is not starting

Tags: 8.1, update, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-535

while upgrading my windows phone to 10 it stopped in middle because of power problem.now i am unable to start my windows phone and even i tried to hard reset but it doesn't work.when i connect my phone to power adopter it just keeps restarting. moving gears comes and then phone restarts again and again .please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downgrading your phone to back to Windows 8.1? There is already a detailed explanation of how to do this in the question, [How to rollback from Windows 10 Technical Preview?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8811/how-to-rollback-from-windows-10-technical-preview)

It is a simple process, but you will lose almost all of your data saved onto your phone. Follow the directions given [here by Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987). You basically just download the [Windows Device Recovery Tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525569), connect your phone to your computer, and let it run.